# How do I create and input data into BubbleSortable (interface) objects?

Tags: java

I need to sort a list of numbers in order using an interface, BubbleSortable and a class, BubbleSort, whose method, bubbleSort, takes in a BubbleSortable [].

I've tried creating a List, ArrayList, and a BubbleSortable array (BubbleSortable a = new BubbleSortable [someLength];), however, I was never able to input any data into the list—I would get an error saying String or int cannot be converted to BubbleSortable.

Here is interface BubbleSortable:

```
public interface BubbleSortable {
  boolean lessThan ( BubbleSortable bs );
}
```

Class BubbleSort:

```
public class BubbleSort {
  /**/
  public static void bubbleSort ( BubbleSortable [] list ) {
    /**/
    int len;
    BubbleSortable temp;
    /**/
    len=list.length;
    /**/
    for ( int p=0; p<len-1; ++p ) {
      for ( int i=0; i<len-1-p; ++i ) {
        if ( list[i+1].lessThan(list[i]) ) {
          temp=list[i+1];
          list[i+1]=list[i];
          list[i]=temp;
        }
      }
    }
    /**/
    return;
  }
}
```

and some class where I want to sort a list

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
/**/
public class TestR implements {
    /**/
    public static void main (String [] arg) { 
        BubbleSortable [] bsList = new BubbleSortable [5];
    }
        public static boolean lessThan ( BubbleSortable bs ) { 
                      // don't know how to work with BubbleSortable object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need:

- A class Bubble that `implements` BubbleSortable, takes an `int` in its constructor and stores it in a private field.
- A function `getNumber()` in BubbleSortable, that you'll `override` in Bubble so it returns its private `int` field.

Then you can create your array in your main function:

```
BubbleSortable[] bsArray = new Bubble[]
            {new Bubble(5), new Bubble(2), new Bubble(4)}; // some numbers to be sorted
```

And sort it:

```
BubbleSort.bubbleSort(bsArray);
```

If you have any problem sorting your array once you did all that, please make a new post.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks so much, this has helped a lot!